# Extending and replacing existing Interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am currently working on a Plugin for Mongoose. As Part for this the Options Interface needs to be extended as it can hold additional attributes. To achieve this I'm doing the following.

I use [Declaration-Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) so I create a TypingsFile like this

**SomeTypings.d.ts**

```
declare Interface QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions {
  MyCustomField: string
}
```

Also I Incldue this Typings File in my tsconfig.json

**tsconfig.json**

```js
include : [
  ...
  "./src/types/SomeTypings.d.ts"
]
```

Sadly this is not working. Declare Merging only works if I declare two interfaces with the same name in the same File. Importing and defining an interface will trigger a naming conflict.

Any Idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 5):

OK, so the answer was pretty simple. Basically I made 2 mistakes

1. I did not declare the module containing the interface I want to extend
2. I did not add typeRoots in the tsconfig CompilerOptions (the "include" from my question is irrelevant for this)

### 1 - The Typings (mongoose.d.ts)

I created a mongoose.d.ts (the name is not important but I prefer to name it like the module I extend) file in *./src/types*. Here I extend my interfaces like this

**mongoose.d.ts**

```
interface SpecialOptions {
  verySpecialStuff: string
  enable: boolean
}

declare module 'mongoose' {
  export interface ModelOptions {
    MyNewKey: SpecialOptions
  }
}
```

This will extend the existing interface ModelOptions in mongoose by *MyNewKey*

### 2 - Configuring the Compiler

By default the compiler will just check *./node_modules/@types* for Types. So you need to tell it to also include your custom types. To do this the compilerOptions need to be extended like this

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
// ...
  "compilerOptions" : {
    // ...
    "typeRoots" : [
      "src/types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```